# Is FirebaseMessagingService an intent service?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to save all the messages received in the onMessageReceived of the service inside a SQLite db.

I was planning to open the db, insert the data and close the db. This would work well with an intent service as all the calls to the onMessageReceived would be queued and thus execute one by one.

However if the onMessageReceived gets called concurrently for multiple messages, it could cause issues of the Db being closed while another call is trying to write thus leading to issues.

Can anyone confirm what kind of behaviour i should expect.

If it is not an intent service, i might have to look at the DB singleton pattern and synchronization blocks

Comment: Have you checked out offline usage of firebase?

Comment: It's a service then... but does it receive messages at the same time? From what i have seen multiple messages are received one by one. However i am not so sure if it'll always be the case.

Comment: @JadavLalit i don't think the persistence of firebase db is going to help me with FCM. Is that what you are refering to?

Comment: just `Log.d()` the value of the current thread inside `onMessageReceived` and you will see by yourself

Comment: @pskink i have.. usually it executes one by one. However i can't be sure without knowing how they handle the worker thread and intents internally.

Comment: so what do you see on the `logcat` when you `Log.d()` the current thread?

Comment: shows a gap of around 2 milli seconds between messages. This is why i am worried. Might cause an overlap of the DB being open and getting closed while the other call is working

Comment: If this still continues acting like this, i probably will have to resort to sharedpreferences instead lol... atleast the connection issues will be solved

Comment: i mean what `Thread` do you see on the `logcat`?

Comment: different threads and different pools. So i guess synchronized write and single db would be the only option available to me.

Comment: what stops you from using [Synchronized Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) then? or using a `Handler`? or another `IntentService`?

Comment: Great point about the intent service man... I had completely forgotten about that... Ya that would solve my issue .. thanks buddy.. post that in the answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, `FirebaseMessagingService` extends `Service` directly, so it is not an `IntentService`.

[Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService)
Snapshot:

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check `LinkedBlockingDeque<>` class which queues your requests and can be performed in background sequentially. 
Check below sample class of mine -

```java
public class Processor implements Runnable {

    private final LinkedBlockingDeque<Task> mTaskQueue = new LinkedBlockingDeque<Task>();
    private boolean mExecuteTask = true;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        // You can put some end  condition if needed
        while (mExecuteTask) {
            Task task;
            try {
                // Waits if necessary until an element becomes available
                task = (Task) mTaskQueue.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                continue; // re-test the condition on the eclosing while
            }
            if (task != null) {
                task.runnable.run();
            }
        }
    }

    // Call this method to put Runnable in Queue.
    public synchronized void put(int id, Runnable runnable) {
        try {
            Task task = new Task();
            task.runnable = runnable;
            task.id = id; // someUniqueId to avoid duplication
            // Check Id of tasks already present in Queue
            mTaskQueue.addLast(task);
        } catch (IllegalStateException ie) {
            throw new Error(ie);
        }
    }

    private static class Task {
        public Runnable runnable;
        // Unique Id of task
        public int id;
    }
}
```